# Spark Partitionby timestamp to year month date on the fly without adding columns

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I am trying to partition the delta output of spark job based on timestamp column. My dataframe has 2 columns:

```
userid, last_login
1234, "2023-11-25T05:22:13.433Z"
5678, "2023-11-26T05:22:12.123Z"
```

I dont want to add additional columns in the output delta and in the last step while I am writing the output using write & save :

```
dataframe.wite.format("delta").partitionBy("year", "month", "day").save("my_location")
```

Is there any way I can create yyyy, mm, dd on the fly? I am using spark scala for this job.

I tried using same code dataframe.wite.format("delta").partitionBy("year", "month", "day").save("my_location") but its not working for me and saying columns not found kind of error.

Answer (score 1):

You do need to specify what year, month and day are.

```scala
dataframe
  .select(
    $"userid",
    $"last_login",
    year($"last_login").as("year"),
    month($"last_login").as("month"),
    dayofmonth($"last_login").as("day")
  )
  .write.format("delta").partitionBy("year", "month", "day").save("my_location")
```

It can't be more "on-the-fly" than this.

I suspect what you might be concerned about is whether these columns will be saved to parquet files, wasting space. No, they will not. The output will be similar to this:

```
your_table/
  year=2023/
    month=10/
      day=26/
        part-0000-blah.parquet
        part-0001-blah.parquet
      day=27/
        part-0000-blah.parquet
        part-0001-blah.parquet
```

These parquet files will only contain `userid` and `last_login` columns. Partition values are stored in directory structure and when reading data they will be simply reconstructed from path.